# Tornar campo obrigatório dependendo da resposta

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou com um formulário médico, e foi pedida a seguinte alteração:

Se o campo 1 for checado = 1, tornar campo 2 obrigatório. Se não for checado não tornar como obrigatório.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
const camp1 = document.getElementById('campo1');
const camp2 = document.getElementById('campo2');
const btn_sub = document.getElementById('btn-submit');

btn_sub.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(camp1.checked && !camp2.checked) {
    alert('Campo 2 obrigatório');
    return;
  }
  alert('É Válido')
});
```

```html
<input id="campo1" type="checkbox">1
<br>
<input id="campo2" type="checkbox">2
<button id="btn-submit">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Então a questão é o seguinte, os campos desse meu formulário todos são obrigatorios, e eu queria que exemplo:
 se eu selecionar 1 na resposta de cima, a questão de baixa que é obrigatoria, deixar salvar sem preencher, queria retirar o obrigatoriedade.

<b>REGRA</b>
diaposah: a regra para o campo 'Necessitará de diálise após a alta hospitalar?' era 'obrigatório se stvaUTI e/ou stvahosp = 1'. Ela deve ser alterada para 'obrigatório se stvahosp = 1'

Comment: coloquei os formuario para download no link abaixo

[ [4shared.com/office/G-AI_xQcba/formulario.html? ]

Comment: não, ainda não consegui resolver esse problema!

Comment: Clica nesse notepad online https://shrib.com/yrlt9iuZQNZGJ1w

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7xdjqbbL/

Comment: O Input "Status vital na alta hospitalar" 2 = Morto - torna a questão "Necessitará de diálise após a alta hospitalar?" Obrigatoria

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo , vê se isto resulta, acrescentei um id ao input que diz "sim", https://jsfiddle.net/7xdjqbbL/6/

Comment: não funcionou :(

Comment: sim, deu erro na linha btn_sub.addEventListener('click', function() {

Comment: QUal é o erro @LeonardoMacedo? Tens de colocar o id do teu botão de submit no javascript, nesta linha `const btn_sub = document.getElementById('ID_DO_BOTAO');`

Comment: Eu cliquei inspecionei a pagina do meu navegador e da o seguinte erro ----- " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at AltaUTI?cadastroId=164:706 "

Comment: Faz o que te disse no cometário em cima, tens de pôr o id do teu botão no javascript

Comment: o erro no do console saiu, só que não funcionou ainda

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53785/discussion-on-answer-by-miguel-tornar-campo-obrigatorio-depenendo-da-resposta)

Answer (score 1):

```
var camp1 = $('campo1');
var camp2 = $('campo1');
if(camp1.val() == 1){
  camp2.attr('required', true);
}
```

**Pode usar getElementById**

```
var camp1 = getElementById('#camp1');
var camp2 = getElementById('#camp2');
if(camp1.val() == 1){
  camp2.attr('required', true);
}
```

Comment: Então a questão é o seguinte, os campos desse meu formulário todos são obrigatorios, e eu queria que exemplo:
 se eu selecionar 1 na resposta de cima, a questão de baixa que é obrigatoria, deixar salvar sem preencher, queria retirar o obrigatoriedade.

<b>REGRA</b>
diaposah: a regra para o campo 'Necessitará de diálise após a alta hospitalar?' era 'obrigatório se stvaUTI e/ou stvahosp = 1'. Ela deve ser alterada para 'obrigatório se stvahosp = 1'

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo Poderia passar o formulário para que eu possa analisar?

Comment: bom dia, http://www.4shared.com/office/G-AI_xQcba/formulario.html?
coloquei o formuario para download.

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo fiquei um bom tempo sem mexer no PC aí não deu para estar passando aqui para dar uma olhada. Você já conseguiu solucionar o problema ?

Answer (score 1):

Segue exemplo usando `JavaScript`, `Jquery` e a função `required` do HTML5.

```js
$('.pergunta').change(function() {
  var chars = parseInt(this.value);
  if (chars === 1) {
    $('#retorno').html('<input type="checkbox" name="campo2" required=""> Obrigatório');
    return;
  } else {
    $('#retorno').html('<input type="checkbox" name="campo2"> Não Obrigatório');
    return;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="pergunta" name="checado" value="1" required>Sim
<input type="checkbox" class="pergunta" name="checado" value="2" required>Não

<div id="retorno"></div>
```

Espero ajudar.

Comment: Então a questão é o seguinte, os campos desse meu formulário todos são obrigatorios, e eu queria que exemplo:
 se eu selecionar 1 na resposta de cima, a questão de baixa que é obrigatoria, deixar salvar sem preencher, queria retirar o obrigatoriedade.

<b>REGRA</b>
diaposah: a regra para o campo 'Necessitará de diálise após a alta hospitalar?' era 'obrigatório se stvaUTI e/ou stvahosp = 1'. Ela deve ser alterada para 'obrigatório se stvahosp = 1'